# How to set textfield placeholder's value to time picker's selected value

Tags: swift, xcode

On "func can()" pop up shows a textfield on which we click & a time picker shows.I want to set textfield placeholder value to that selected picker's value

```
@IBAction func can(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let alertController : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Confirm Order ?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alertController.addTextField
    {
        (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Expected Time"
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myTargetFunction), for: .touchDown)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive) {
        (UIAlertAction) in
        }
        let CANAction = UIAlertAction(title: "SUBMIT", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
        (UIAlertAction) in
        // self.actionCancelOrderApiCall()
        }
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(CANAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@objc func myTargetFunction(textField: UITextField) {
    var datePicker : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 500, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 250))
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    if datePicker.isHidden == false{
        tblV.isHidden = true
        atchment1.isHidden = true
    }
    self.view.addSubview(datePicker)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below changes should make it work

`textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myTargetFunction(sender:)), for: .touchDown)`

change your method signature to

`@objc func myTargetFunction(sender: UITextField)`

inside `myTargetFunction()`,

`sender.placeholderText = datePicker.date`

Comment: Thank 4 ur answer Hisenberg, but I literally wanted to know how to get the selected picker's value into the textfield's placeholder?How ever I applied ur suggested changes it doesn't showed any error yet.Please give ur answer Sir.

Comment: check updated answer. You have to add `DateFormatter` in order to get the date in proper string format.